# index on fs readfile in for loop in nodejs

Tags: node.js

I write following nodejs script. In the script, I expected the `index` inside `fs.readFile` is storeing incremental value. 
By the way the `note_files` is an array and it stores 6 of file pathes. In my case, there's need of getting current file path by `index` value inside `fs.readFile` block.

So, how do I get for-loop index value inside `fs.readFile` block?

```js
for(index=0;  index< note_files.length ; index++){

    console.log(index) ; 

    fs.readFile( path.relative( __dirname , note_files[index] ) , 'utf8', function(err, data) {

        content = data;

        console.log(index) ; // all of then are same value "7". the desired result value is 0 to 7, indexicaly. 

        // main() ;
    });

    console.log(index) ; 

}
```

Comment: Do you want to sequentially go through the files, or load them all concurrently and loop over them once they are all loaded?

Comment: Why not just use readFileSync?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case I recommend using Promises as they make it easier to reason about this type of problem. You can use the `util` module from the node standard library to promisify a method like `readFile`.

```
const { promisify } = require("util");
const path = require("path")
const fs = require("fs");

const readFileAsync = promisify(fs.readFile);

const note_files = [/* insert filepaths here */];

Promise.all(
  note_files.map(filepath => readFileAsync(path.relative(__dirname, filepath)))
).then(files => {
  files.forEach((file, i) => {
    console.log(i);
  });
}).catch(err => {
  console.log("an error occured while loading some of the files. Error:", err)
});
```

This code will map the file paths to promises, pack them together into 1 and give out read files. Only then we loop over the files and access the index.

Comment: Can I invoke `main()` function to deal with file content `file` in the promise then block?

Comment: Yes you can. What does `main()` do? Inside `files.forEach` block the `file` is an array of bytes.

Comment: @Reijo If there a lot of files, say close to 3000 and each file over 1MB will this cause a slow down now that all the filecontents are in memory?

Comment: @ChrisTomAlx When there are so many files, you should probably consider batching the work. So limit the number of files you read in and process at once. You could either try a simpler approach with a for-await loop with limited number of files, or a more sophisticated one with a "task queue" and a max population of files, with a task representing reading and processing of one file.
If you are really into performance than note that a lot of small files are always slower than few big files. In that case you could check out worker threads in nodejs https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html

Comment: @ChrisTomAlx [pm2](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/) is a nice tool for managing and monitoring your nodejs process. Maybe that will help you analyzing your needs of your program.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions @Reijo. I ended up going with a promise based mechanism where I asynchronously read each file.